# Доступ к элементам Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется `toolbar`:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Инициализация:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне получить из кода доступ к `ImageView` для смены картинки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.someImage);
```

Comment: Непонятно как, но оно работает) Спасибо.

Comment: @Pollux, если ответ решает задачу, то вы можете отметить его "верным"